# Find documents according to referenced objectid

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am unable to retrieve all of the documents referenced in an array in a collection. I do not know how to do. Could you help me please ?

Here is my collection where there are the id

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b4c2e4ff64f92f0dd70b"),
    "desigantion" : "UE1",
    "coefficent" : 15,
    "matieres" : [ 
        ObjectId("60a3b356e4ff64f92f0dd1fc"), 
        ObjectId("60a3b856e4ff64f92f0de49b"), 
        ObjectId("60a3b8a0e4ff64f92f0de5dc"), 
        ObjectId("60a3b8eee4ff64f92f0de701"), 
        ObjectId("60a3b5ace4ff64f92f0ddaaa")
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b6dce4ff64f92f0ddf7f"),
    "desigantion" : "UE2",
    "coefficent" : 15,
    "matieres" : [ 
        ObjectId("60a3b67ee4ff64f92f0ddde3"), 
        ObjectId("60a3ba8be4ff64f92f0dee6f"), 
        ObjectId("60a3b629e4ff64f92f0ddcd5")
    ]
}
```

And here is my collection of "matieres"

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b5ace4ff64f92f0ddaaa"),
    "nom" : "C++",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Jardin",
            "prenom" : "Pierre"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "LaStreet",
            "prenom" : "Bernard"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "Boiserie",
            "prenom" : "Theo"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b629e4ff64f92f0ddcd5"),
    "nom" : "Anglais",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Michelle",
            "prenom" : "Conry-Fidone"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 6
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b67ee4ff64f92f0ddde3"),
    "nom" : "PPP",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Giraud",
            "prenom" : "Laurent"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "Luret",
            "prenom" : "Marilyn"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 2
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b856e4ff64f92f0de49b"),
    "nom" : "Algo",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Simon",
            "prenom" : "Carine"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 9
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b8a0e4ff64f92f0de5dc"),
    "nom" : "Java",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Hasbani",
            "prenom" : "Abdel"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "Provot",
            "prenom" : "Laurent"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "Bouhours",
            "prenom" : "Cedric"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 8
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3b8eee4ff64f92f0de701"),
    "nom" : "BDD",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Lafourcade",
            "prenom" : "Pierre"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "Brigoulet",
            "prenom" : "Pascale"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 5
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60a3ba8be4ff64f92f0dee6f"),
    "nom" : "Economie",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Goi",
            "prenom" : "Isabelle"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 5
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bf67e842ecdb7d4268cc7e"),
    "nom" : "Maths",
    "coefficient" : 5,
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Jean",
            "prenom" : "Pierre"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "LaStreet",
            "prenom" : "Patrick"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "Buisson",
            "prenom" : "Jules"
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "fr.iut.blankproject.domain.Matiere"
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d1d9d364ccf255491679de"),
    "nom" : "PPP2",
    "professeurs" : [ 
        {
            "nom" : "Giraud",
            "prenom" : "Laurent"
        }, 
        {
            "nom" : "Luret",
            "prenom" : "Marilyn"
        }
    ],
    "coefficient" : 6
}
```

I want to get all the subjects where "designation = UE1" from the "matieres" array. Thanks !

Comment: You can use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation query to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('mainCollection').aggregate([{
        $match: {
            desigantion: "UE1"
        }
    } {
        $unwind: "$matieres"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "matieres",
            localField: "matieres",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "data"
        }
    }
])
```

below are the steps

- from your main collection I have found out all the data sets which match my condition `desigantion: "UE1"`.
- then I have tried to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the key `matieres`.
- finally, I have used [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) my `matieres` key to `matieres` collection.